# Calling function within method python class

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

```
class NN(object):

    def __init__(...):
        [...] #some intialization of the class

    #define a recursive function to return  a vector which has atleast one non-zero element
    @staticmethod
    def generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size):
        temp = np.random.binomial(1, dropout_prob, size)
        return temp if not sum(temp) else generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size)

    def compute_dropout(self, activations, dropout_prob = 0.5):
        [...]
        mult = np.copy(activations)          
        temp = generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size = activations.shape[0])
        mult[:,i] = temp            
        activations*=mult
        return activations

    def fit(self, ...):
        compute_dropout(...)
```

> I want to create a function within my class which is called by a
>   class-method. This function is recursive and is meant to return a
>   vector of 0s and 1s only if the vector has atleast one non-zero
>   element
>
> The error I'm getting is "Nameerror: name 'generate_random_nodes' is
>   not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything defined inside a class must be referenced by qualified name, either looked up on the class directly, or on an instance of it. So the simplest fix here is to explicitly call `NN.generate_random_nodes` for the recursive call, and `self.generate_random_nodes` in the initial calls to it (only showing methods with changes):

```
@staticmethod
def generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size):
    temp = np.random.binomial(1, dropout_prob, size)
    # Must explicitly qualify recursive call
    return temp if not sum(temp) else NN.generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size)

def compute_dropout(self, activations, dropout_prob = 0.5):
    [...]
    mult = np.copy(activations)          
    # Can call static on self just fine, and avoids hard-coding class name
    temp = self.generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size=activations.shape[0])
    mult[:,i] = temp            
    activations*=mult
    return activations
```

Note that as a CPython implementation detail on Python 3.x, referencing `__class__` inside a method defined in a class creates a closure scope that gives you access to the class it was defined it, allowing you to avoid repeating yourself by explicitly specifying the class, so `generate_random_nodes` could be:

```
@staticmethod
def generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size):
    temp = np.random.binomial(1, dropout_prob, size)
    # Must qualify recursive call
    return temp if not sum(temp) else __class__.generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size)
```

which has a couple advantages:

1. Nested scope lookup of `__class__` slightly faster than global scope lookup of `NN`, and
2. If the name of your `NN` class changes during development, you don't need to change `generate_random_nodes` at all (because it's implicitly getting a reference to the class it was defined in).

You could also (without relying on CPython implementation details) change it to a `classmethod` to get the same basic benefit:

```
@classmethod
def generate_random_nodes(cls, dropout_prob, size):
    temp = np.random.binomial(1, dropout_prob, size)
    # Must qualify recursive call
    return temp if not sum(temp) else cls.generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size)
```

since `classmethod`s receive a reference to the class they were called on (the class of the instance they were called on if called on an instance). This is a slight abuse of `classmethod` (`classmethod`'s only intended use is for alternate constructors in class hierarchies where subclasses need to be able to be constructed using the alternate constructor without overloading it in the subclass); it's perfectly legal, just slightly unorthodox.

As discussed below in the comments:

1. Python is bad at recursion
2. Your recursion condition is backwards (you return `temp` only if the `sum` of it is `0`, meaning `temp` is an array of all zeroes), which dramatically increases the chance of recursion, and makes a recursion error nearly certain for sufficiently high `dropout_prob`/`size` arguments.

So you want to change `temp if not sum(temp) else <recursive call>` to `temp if sum(temp) else <recursive call>`, or for better performance/obviousness given it's a `numpy` array, `temp if temp.any() else <recursive call>`. And while that's likely to make the chance of recursion errors pretty small to start with, if you want to be extra careful, just change to a `while` loop based approach that can't risk indefinite recursion:

```
@staticmethod
def generate_random_nodes(dropout_prob, size):
    while True:
        temp = np.random.binomial(1, dropout_prob, size)
        if temp.any():
            return temp
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, if I may ask another question, I'm seeing a the following message when I run `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.  This is making me wonder if solving a problem recursively in python is not optimal

Comment: @Josh: You are correct there. Python (at least the CPython reference interpreter) is incapable of applying the tail call optimization, and (to prevent an actual C stack overflow) by default raises an exception if you descend more than 1000 frames (checkable with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`, changable with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, but changing it just risks actual stack overflow crashes, not a "nice" exception). Recursive solutions are usually a bad idea if they recurse indefinitely. In this case, it seems like a simple `while` loop would be the way to go.

Comment: That said, I think your function is backwards. It keeps making arrays until it gets an array of all zeroes, then returns the zeroes. I think you wanted it the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid using a `while` loop. But if you think about it statistically, I'm trying to create a vector of 0s and 1s with a random distribution, with a 50% probability of selecting a 1.. so we really shouldn't run into an indefinite recursive state

Comment: @Josh: I updated the answer to include this info. I'll note that using `sum` for the test is quite inefficient (it can't short-circuit, and it has to convert each numpy value to a Python level `int` one by one as it goes), when `numpy` already provides a `.any()` method that short-circuits and operates directly on the C level values without conversion.

Comment: Thanks I will try that